# Filter drop-down options in a django form based on logged-in user

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django form to create a new instance (record) of a class called `Ticket`. The users can be from different `clients` so I need to limit the options displayed in the drop-downs to the logged-in user's client basically. `client` is an attribute of a class that I have defined in `admin.py`, which defines the `client` name of the `user`. I know that I am on the right path, but I have a difficult making this work since I need to extract the `client` of the logged-in `User` and then use it to filter the fields (for example `business`) when initializing the form, any help would be appreciated? Please consider that I have multiple fields that should be filtered so if there is a way to do this once for all of the fields it would be great:

**models.py**

```
class Business(models.Model):
    client=models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_active':True},)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False, unique=True,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, )
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True,)



class Ticket(MMRequestAttributes):    
    no=models.CharField('Ticket Number',max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4,null=False, blank=False, editable=False, unique=True)
    subject=models.CharField('Subject',max_length=100,null=False, blank=False)
    business=models.ForeignKey('Business', on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'is_active':True},)

    class Meta:
        permissions=(('view_ticket','Can see tickets'),)
```

**views.py**

```
def new_ticket(request):
    form=NewTicket(request.user)
    return render(request,'mmrapp/new_ticket.html',{'form':form})
```

**admin.py**

```
class UserExtend(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False,null=False,)
    client=models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'is_active': True},)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='User Extends'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Ticket 
from .admin import UserExtend

class NewTicket(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,user):
        self.business.queryset=business.objects.filter(client.id=userextend.client_id)

    class Meta:
        model=Ticket
        fields = ('subject','business')
```

**new-ticket.html**

```
{% extends 'mmrapp/__l_single_column.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block main_col %}
    <h1>New Ticket</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="new-ticket">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock main_col %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it in the right way, just change the `__init__` to this

```
class NewTicket(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewTicket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            client_id = UserExtend.objects.values_list('client_id', flat=True).get(user=user)
            self.fields['business'].queryset=Business.objects.filter(client__id=client_id)
        except UserExtend.DoesNotExist:
            ### there is not userextend corresponding to this user, do what you want 
            pass


    class Meta:
        model=Ticket
        fields = ('subject','business')
```

also, don't forget to pass the request.user to the Form in your view.

Comment: it did not throw an error and it rendered the form, but there is no blanks and it is just the title of the form and a submit button

Comment: `business` was inherited from another class and it is not really defined under `Ticket`, I don't think that would cause the problem?

Comment: the rendered form didn't bring both of `subject` and `business`? or just `business`?

Comment: it did not bring any of then

Comment: oh sorry, i just forget to call the super __init__

Comment: I applied the changes, it is the same, it does not bring any of the fields

Comment: I used the latest edit and still the problem is the same, no fields displayed!

Comment: does the FromModel work without overriding the `__init__` ?

Comment: yeah, there is no error, it renders, it only shows `New Ticket` as the title and then just a `submit` button

Comment: can you add `MMRequestAttributes` to the question ?

Comment: also the template(the part of it that renders the form)

Comment: just added real definitions of the models and html template

Comment: the only possible way that I could think of it, is that you give the rendered form to the view context with a different name than `form`

Comment: print the form in the view and check it there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178400/discussion-between-ibo-and-changak).